# How does the spell attack bonus work?

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting

I'm new to D&D and I have never played as a casting character doses anyone know how the spell attack bonus works.

Comment: And welcome to our stack! Please take the [tour] to learn more about how we operate here. Do you have a copy of the [basic rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules) or a player's handbook?

Comment: Thanks and Yes I have the player's handbook, but I don't really understand how most of the spell  casting works

Comment: If you've got more questions, I definitely recommend searching first for existing questions.